# Cross Apply used Sub Query not Return Result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply

I want to extract version data from the `deviceinfo` column. For that I am using **Cross Apply**.

```
Order
----------------------------------
OrdeId       DeviceInfo                
----------------------------------    
10      PageSize|BGColor|3000|V1.0
11      PageSize|BGColor|3000|V2.0
12      PageSize|BGColor|3000|V3.0
----------------------------------
```

I have used the below query

```
Select * From 
(
    Select OrderId, DeviceInfo, Value, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By DeviceInfo Order By OrderId Asc) As Rn
    FROM Order As Ord
    Cross Apply STRING_SPLIT(DeviceInfo, '|') As Di
    Where IsNull(Ord.DeviceInfo,'') != '' And OrderId='10'
)A Where A.Rn=4 And A.OrderId='10'
```

I got the Result.

```
OrderId       DeviceInfo              Value  Rn
------------------------------------------------
10      PageSize|BGColor|3000|V1.0     V1.0  4
```

If I use the query without orderid filter in sub query I got an **Empty result**.

```
Select * From 
(
    Select OrderId, DeviceInfo, Value, ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By DeviceInfo Order By OrderId Asc) As Rn
    FROM Order As Ord
    Cross Apply STRING_SPLIT(DeviceInfo, '|') As Di
    Where IsNull(Ord.DeviceInfo,'') != ''
)A Where A.Rn=4 And A.OrderId='10'
```

Kindly help me to fix this issue

Comment: What is the result you want? Using the ROW_NUMBER you'll only get one result (per DeviceInfo), the one with lowest OrderId. If you don't filter the subquery, you'll get OrderId's < 10

Comment: I ran both of your example queries and they return the exact same result set. Can you try to re-explain the problem you are seeing and provide any errors as well.

Comment: Please don't use functions over columns in WHERE part. It could be bad for performance. Better use `Ord.DeviceInfo IS NOT NULL OR Ord.DeviceInfo != ''`

Comment: @gofr1 In this case, they want to ignore both NULL AND blank. So it should be `AND`. However, they technically only need `WHERE Ord.DeviceInfo <> ''`, nulls will automatically be filtered out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible explanation for the unexpected results is the combination of the following issues:

- The wrong use of `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function call. `ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By DeviceInfo Order By OrderId Asc)` numbers rows in random and unexpected order.
- Using `STRING_SPLIT()` to extract the substring by position is a tricky apporach. As is [mentioned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) in the documentation, *the output rows might be in any order* and *the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string*.

In your case (if you want to extract the substring by position) you may try a JSON-based approach to parse the `DeviceInfo` column. You need to transform the data into a valid JSON array (`PageSize|BGColor|3000|V1.0` into `["PageSize","BGColor","3000","V1.0"]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`. The result from the `OPENJSON()` call is a table with columns `key`, `value` and `type` and the `key` column holds the 0-based index of the element in the specified array.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Order] (
   OrderId int,
   DeviceInfo varchar(1000)               
)
INSERT INTO [Order] (OrderId, DeviceInfo)
VALUES
   (10, 'PageSize|BGColor|3000|V1.0'),
   (11, 'PageSize|BGColor|3000|V2.0'),
   (12, 'PageSize|BGColor|3000|V3.0')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT OrderId, DeviceInfo, [Value]
FROM [Order] AS o
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(o.DeviceInfo, '|', '","'), '"]')) AS j
WHERE o.OrderId = 10 AND j.[key] = '3'
```

Result:

```
OrderId DeviceInfo                 Value
----------------------------------------
10      PageSize|BGColor|3000|V1.0 V1.0
```

Comment: Be sure that your strings do not contain any comma (`,`).

Comment: @FabianPijcke The comma (`,`) is not a problem. Double quotes (`"`) are a possible issue, but if the OP uses SQL Server 2017+, `REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(o.DeviceInfo, 'json'), '|', '","')` solves this issue.